# How to draw two lines in tikz that cross an axis at the same point?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In tikz/pgf I would like to draw two lines that cross a coordinate system's Y axis at the same point. I have no clue how to start it. I only know how to draw X and Y axes.
I attach an image what I would like to achieve.
Thanks,
bcsikos

[image]

Comment: If you can draw the axes, that means you can draw straight lines, I presume? That means that you in principle can make that entire diagram, because straight lines are all there is in the diagram :) A little bit of math will help you find appropriate coordinates for the two crossing lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution without any math, except the simple use of the `calc` library:

[image: two lines crossing at a defined point]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw   (-5,0) -- (5,0)
                (0,-5) -- (0,5);
        
        \coordinate (I) at (0,2);
        \coordinate (A) at (-4,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (-2,0);
        
        \draw   (A) -- ($(A)!2!(I)$)
                (B) -- ($(B)!2!(I)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        
        % axex and grid
        \draw[gray!15] (-3.6,-3.6) grid [step=0.5] (3.6,3.6);
        \draw[-latex] (-3.6,0) -- (3.6,0) node [right] {$x$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-3.6) -- (0,3.6) node [above] {$y$};
        \foreach \i in {-3.5,-3.0,...,-.5,0.5,1,1.5,...,3.5}
        \draw (\i,0.05) -- (\i,-0.05) node [below] {\tiny $\i$};
        \foreach\i in {-3.5,-3.0,...,-.5,0.5,1,1.5,...,3.5}
        \draw (0.05,\i) -- (-0.05,\i) node [left]  {\tiny $\i$};
        
        \draw[blue,line width=3pt] (-2,-1)--(1,2);
        \draw[cyan,line width=3pt] (-1,-1)--(1,3);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

you have:
[image]

In fact if the point on y axis is (0,1), you have, for example the lines
y=x+1 and y= 2x+1 witch cross in (0,1) the y axis.
You have to choose 2 points for each of these lines to draw them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with any math, except not simple use of the calc library:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw   (-5,0) -- (5,0) (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\draw plot[domain=-4:4, samples=2] (\x,{0.5*\x+2});
\draw plot[domain=-2:2, samples=2] (\x,{\x+2});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lines]

Comment: I don't see any use of `calc` library ... are you make a joke ;-).

Comment: LOL for the caption ;)

Comment: @Zarko: Yes - just an alternative solution with a reference to SebGlav's answer